# Mount (link) a single file from a docker container volume

Tags: docker

I created a docker volume called `ssh` that I mount to another container in `~/.ssh`. That's ok.

I now want to create another volume which has files in `~/`, for example, `.gitconfig`

How could I mount (link) this file in my `~/.gitconfig` with a container volume?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to mount a single file from a docker volume.

For a local volume you could mount the local files

```
$ docker run -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/home/_data/.gitconfig:/.gitconfig busybox ls -l /.gitconfig
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Jun  4 17:02 /.gitconfig
```

Comment: This is possible, but I want to link a file from a volume container, not from the host.

Comment: Oh I see. I don't think you can mount a single file from a docker volume normally.  Local volumes are just a directory on your system though, so you could mount local files like above but it will come from `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volumename>/_data/.gitconfig`